# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode' HDF5

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to open a HDF5 file in Python using the following code:

```
with h5py.File('example.hdf5', 'r') as f:
    ls = list(f.keys())
    dat = f.get('data')
    dt = np.array(dat)
```

However, I get this error when executing the last line:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

dat has the following class:

```
h5py._hl.group.Group'
```

Anyone knows where the error could come?

The output from iterating inside the file is the following. How can I access inside each part of the file:

```
checking hdf5 file
/data is a Group
/data/model_cints is a Dataset
/hdf5_track_times is a Dataset
/meta is a Group
/meta/package is a Group
/meta/package/h5py is an object Dataset
/meta/package/numpy is an object Dataset
/meta/package/pypfilt is an object Dataset
/meta/package/python is an object Dataset
/meta/package/scipy is an object Dataset
/meta/package/toml is an object Dataset
/meta/param is a Group
/meta/param/component is a Group
/meta/param/component/model is an object Dataset
/meta/param/component/obs is a Group
/meta/param/component/obs/LatLon is an object Dataset
/meta/param/component/summary_table is a Group
/meta/param/component/summary_table/model_cints is an object Dataset
/meta/param/component/time is an object Dataset
/meta/param/data_dir is an object Dataset
/meta/param/hist is a Group
/meta/param/hist/extra_cols is a Dataset
/meta/param/hist/px_count is a Dataset
/meta/param/hist/wind_shift is a Dataset
/meta/param/hist/wind_size is a Dataset
/meta/param/last_n_periods is a Dataset
/meta/param/minimal_estimation_run is a Dataset
/meta/param/model is a Group
/meta/param/model/param_max is a Dataset
/meta/param/model/param_min is a Dataset
/meta/param/obs is a Group
/meta/param/obs/LatLon is a Group
/meta/param/obs/LatLon/sdev is a Dataset
/meta/param/out_dir is an object Dataset
/meta/param/prng_seed is a Dataset
/meta/param/random is an object Dataset
/meta/param/resample is a Group
/meta/param/resample/method is an object Dataset
/meta/param/resample/reg_toln is a Dataset
/meta/param/resample/regularisation is a Dataset
/meta/param/resample/regularise_or_fail is a Dataset
/meta/param/resample/threshold is a Dataset
/meta/param/scenario is a Group
/meta/param/scenario/id is an object Dataset
/meta/param/scenario/name is an object Dataset
/meta/param/steps_per_unit is a Dataset
/meta/param/summary is a Group
/meta/param/summary/from_first_day is a Dataset
/meta/param/summary/meta is a Group
/meta/param/summary/meta/packages is an object Dataset
/meta/param/summary/only_forecasts is a Dataset
/meta/param/time is a Group
/meta/param/time/start is a Dataset
/meta/param/time/until is a Dataset
/meta/param/tmp_dir is an object Dataset
/meta/prior is a Group
/meta/prior/lat is an object Dataset
/meta/prior/lon is an object Dataset
/meta/prior/speed_lat is an object Dataset
/meta/prior/speed_lon is an object Dataset
/meta/sim is a Group
/meta/sim/cmdline is an object Dataset
```

Comment: Sounds like node `'data'` is a Group and not a Dataset. You can test with `isinstance(node, h5py.Dataset)`. Result should be `True`. Once you find a dataset, you can it read into an array with `dt = f.get.('datset_name')[:]`

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: This is progress. It confirms `'data'` is a Group and that's why you got the error. It also shows which nodes are datasets. [All of the object datasets make me think this was created by MatLab, which might complicate things.] HDF5 is a general data container. At this point an understanding of the data schema is required to interpret the data. Is the schema documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet to test your keys for type (Group or Dataset). It uses the `visititems()` method to recursively walk nodes in your file and report each as a 1) Group, 2) Dataset, 3) Object dataset, or 4) Unknown. Once you find a dataset, you can read and create a NumPy array. However, that is not required. You can work with a h5py dataset object "as-if" it is a NumPy array.

```
def visitor_func(name, node):
    if isinstance(node, h5py.Group):
        print(node.name, 'is a Group')
    elif isinstance(node, h5py.Dataset):
       if (node.dtype == 'object') :
            print (node.name, 'is an object Dataset')
       else:
            print(node.name, 'is a Dataset')   
    else:
        print(node.name, 'is an unknown type')         

#####    

print ('checking hdf5 file')
with h5py.File('example.hdf5', 'r') as h5f:
    h5f.visititems(visitor_func)
```

Comment: I get this output, see above